# Как вывести простой компонент внутри шаблона другого компонента Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, компоненты

Я пытаюсь вызвать в шаблоне обратной связи `(custom:main.feedback)`, вывести соглашение о персональных данных `('bitrix:main.userconsent.request')`

вот место где я пытаюсь его подключить

```
<div class="c-feedback__form-footer">
        <?$parent_component = 'custom:main.feedback';
            $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                "bitrix:main.userconsent.request",
                "",
                Array(
                    "AUTO_SAVE" => "Y",
                    "COMPOSITE_FRAME_MODE" => "A",
                    "COMPOSITE_FRAME_TYPE" => "AUTO",
                    "ID" => "1",
                    "IS_CHECKED" => "Y",
                    "IS_LOADED" => "N"
                ),$parent_component
            );
        ?>



        <input type="hidden" name="PARAMS_HASH" value="<?=$arResult["PARAMS_HASH"]?>">
        <input class="c-feedback__form-button btn btn--1" type="submit" name="submit" value="<?=GetMessage("MFT_SUBMIT")?>" size="100">
    </div>
```

Шаблон стоит .default. Все пути правильные , главный компонент отображается нормально, никаких ошибок нет , но `bitrix:main.userconsent.request` на экран не выводится. В чём может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас ошибка в коде, нужно сделать $parent_component = false (возможно вы не правильно поняли документацию, должно быть значение либо false - если компонент вызывается отдельно (без учёта комплексного компонента, даже если код находится внутри комплексного) либо $component - но это как бы глобальное значение (доступное в комплексном компоненте) внутри компонента и его менять не надо ).